# Disable and Enable Button on Textfield change with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I'm new in reactive programming and also a newbie for using ReactiveUI
so I need a little help.

I'm working on a project, we are using Xamarin-iOS for iOS platform.

I have simple Login ViewController, where I want to enable button immediately when TextField state will change.

I'have those fields.

```
        private string user;
        private string password;
        private ReactiveCommand<Unit,bool> loginCommand;
        private ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit> canselCommand;
```

And I'm using ***this.WhenAnyValue*** method

```
var canLogin = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.user, x => x.password, (userName, password) =>
                                              !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password));

            this.loginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
            () =>
               Observable
                .Return(this.passwordTextField.Text == "Tornike"))
                .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5))
                .TakeUntil(this.canselCommand);
```

Where user and password are private string fields.
And also I have passwordTextField and userNameTextField UILabels on UI.

Everywhere there are redline errors, and I'm scared a little bit.

So how I can just enable the button when textFields will change?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canLogin` should be the second argument passed to the `CreateFromObservable` method. The first argument should be a `Func<IObservable<bool>>`. This should compile:

```
this.loginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
() =>
    Observable
    .Return(this.passwordTextField.Text == "Tornike")
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5))
    .TakeUntil(this.canselCommand), canLogin);
```

But for the `IObservable<bool>` to produce new values and refresh the state of the command whenever `user` or `password` is changed, you should implement `user` and `password` as properties and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever they are set to a new value, e.g.:

```
public string User
{
    get { return user;}
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref user, value);
}
```

Comment: Where must I write logic of my button disable or enable if the state changed?

Comment: canLogin is the place where you want to disable or enable the button

Comment: Commands usually have enable/disable logic inside of them. There is a method CanExecute() on the ICommand interface which ReactiveCommand derives off. The UI will poll this method to determine if it should enable/disable the control. ReactiveCommand's version of CanExecute will return the latest value from the Can Execute observable you pass in as the second parameter to CreateFromObservable.

Comment: @TornikeGomareli: Just raise the PropertyChanged event for the properties. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create properties for using the WhenAnyValue extension method:

```
public string User
{
    get { return user;}
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref user, value);
}

public string Password
{
    get { return password;}
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref password, value);
}
```

And in the command inicialization:

```
this.loginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
        () =>
           Observable
            .Return(this.passwordTextField.Text == "Tornike"))
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5))
            .TakeUntil(this.canselCommand),
canExecute: canLogin);
```

Use User and Password in the WhenAnyValue instead user/password fields. Also, use that properties in your code and in the bind (for TextFields).